# When you really do need to store a password in a database what are best practices

Tags: database, security, passwords

I have a web service using HMAC to verify signed requests. In this scenario there is a key (password) assigned to each caller of my service. The user of course gets that key, but I also need to store the key in my database so that my service can verify the signature of each request coming in.

So this is a case where I really do need to store passwords in the database in a form that I can retrieve and use them. I can't use the best practice of only storing a salted hash of the password in the database.

I could encrypt the keys but then I need to store the encryption key somewhere. This is a fairly common scenario for secured RESTful web services, so the likes of Amazon (AWS) and Microsoft (Azure) have to deal with this problem.

What are best practices in this situation?

Comment: What's wrong with storing the encryption key?

Comment: I wrote a blog post recently on basic password storage: http://blog.brokenbytes.info/2010/12/passwords-beating-the-dead-horse/

Comment: My comment about storing the encryption key was simply to address the fact that I then need to somehow secure the encryption key. Kind of the chicken-egg thing. I can't think of any other way to deal with it, so the problem becomes how to secure the encryption key.

Comment: Is it possible to sign the request with the hash of the user's password?  Then you can just use the hash that gets stored in your database and be more in line with best practices.

Comment: It is possible but I don't see it as accomplishing much. The password in this case really is just a random stream of bytes. If I hash it and then use the hash to sign requests I still need to store the hash. Which if compromised would allow someone to forge requests. It just doesn't avoid the problem that I need access to the same byte array the caller used to sign requests.

Answer (score 3):

The only time password should be stored in a database is if the password is needed to connect to some *other* system.  If one merely needs to check the credentials supplied by some other entity, one should store a hash of the password.

Even if it's necessary to use a password to connect with another party, if some other credentials are needed for you to perform such access (e.g. someone logs into your system, and then you log into another system on their behalf) it's desirable when practical to store the external password encrypted with a hash of the supplied password (but NOT the same hash as the one stored in the database!).  If there are multiple credentials which could be used to log into your server, store a separate copy of the encryption key for the remote password, encrypted using each acceptable credential.

Comment: I disagree. My scenario is clearly a case where I DO need the original password to perform the signature verification. They signed a request with the key, I need to perform the same signature process and compare the two hash's. So this is a case where I don't need to connect to some other system, but I do need to store the password. Asymmetric encryption of the signature is not performant enough, so we must use a shared key.

Comment: If you have to use a protocol which requires both sides to have the same credential, you may be stuck with that.  Will a particular password being used in only one place, or may it be used in multiple places?  If the latter (e.g. if the password is ASCII text), it may be possible to improve security by using a salted hash of the ASCII password instead of the password itself.  Someone who compromised the database could hack a client to accept a pre-hashed value, but that value would only compromise one system instead of all systems using the same ASCII password.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the password (in order to connect to another system, for example), I would recommend putting in somewhere far away from the other information. Perhaps another database, an encrypted file on the file system, etc. This is so if someone gets your main database, they are not guaranteed to also get the passwords in question.

It may be obvious but you want the location of the passwords to be encrypted with another key (to make it less likely that someone who somehow gained access to the primary data source will also gain access to the password data store).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the best practice for your scenario would be to use **public key cryptography**.

Comment: A valid point, but in this scenario asymmetric encryption of the signature is not performant enough.

Comment: @BrettRobi: How about using asymmetric encryption to send a symmetric encryption key used to encrypt the signature? That usually takes care of the performance issue.